# How to fetch an object when user is logged in (auth is not null ) in AngularFire2?

Tags: typescript, angular, observable, angularfire2

I'd like to get user data to a currentUser FirebaseObjectObservable, from '/users/$key' url of my Firebase database where $key equals to auth.uid, when user is logged in. I'd also like when user logs out, currentUser becomes null automatically.

For that I figure I need to use async pipe in my template, yet I can only get currentUser data after login and it stays in memory after logout (the way I've done it). I'd like that it gets null automatically when auth object becomes null.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  currentUser : FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;

    constructor(public af: AngularFire) {

     this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
       console.log(auth);
       this.currentUser = af.database.object('/users/' + auth.uid);
      });
    }

 }
```

I'd be ok to use something like this in my template `{{(currentUser | async)?.email}}`

My lack of knowledge on Observables is problem here, but also AngularFire auth object is different from rxjs/Observable from what I understand.

**Update:**

This is how I've solved it:

```
constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
 this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
   console.log(auth);
   if(auth)
   this.currentUser = af.database.object('/users/' + auth.uid);
   else
    this.currentUser = new FirebaseObjectObservable<any>();
  });
}
```

yet it doesn't feel right to me. Is it ok to do it this way?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can show your uid in your view. You are making it to hard. There is no need to make this one a FireBaseObjectObservable. The auth does everything for you

***component.ts***

```
    export class DashboardComponent {

          email:any;
          userid: string;
          constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
            this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
              console.log(auth.uid);
              this.userid = auth.uid;
              this.email = af.auth.getAuth().auth.email;
             });
        }
    }
```

***component.html***

```
<h1>{{ userid}}</h1>
<h1>{{email}}</h1>
```

This is how you should get all the data out of your user